# Am I correctly excluding the base's fn() function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, sfinae, crtp

I was attempting to do something interesting and it broke on [VC++ 2015](http://rextester.com/FDE50829).  I tried it in [clang](http://rextester.com/TMGKQ48682) and [g++](http://rextester.com/JFOPD61974) and with no compilation or runtime errors.  (Links are to rextester.com demos)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int fn1()    { return 1; }
int fn2(int) { return 2; }

template <typename FN_T, FN_T FN, typename DERIVED>
class test_base
{
    template <typename T = DERIVED, typename = std::enable_if_t<!T::fn_specified>>
    int fn()
    {
        return FN();
    }

public:
    int fn_indirect()
    {
        return static_cast<DERIVED*>(this)->fn();
    }
};

template <typename FN_T, FN_T FN, typename ENABLER = void>
class test_derived : public test_base<FN_T, FN, test_derived<FN_T, FN>>
{
public:
    static constexpr bool fn_specified = false;
};

template <typename FN_T, FN_T FN>
class test_derived<FN_T, FN, std::enable_if_t<FN == &fn2>>
    : public test_base<FN_T, FN, test_derived<FN_T, FN>>
{
    using base = test_base<FN_T, FN, test_derived<FN_T, FN>>;
    friend base;

public:
    static constexpr bool fn_specified = true;
    int fn()
    {
        return FN(1);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    test_derived<decltype(&fn1), &fn1> x1;
    test_derived<decltype(&fn2), &fn2> x2;

    std::cout << x1.fn_indirect() << " ";

    // comment next line out and it'll work in VC++
    std::cout << x2.fn_indirect() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that, if I specify a `fn()` in the derived class, that the base class will not instantiate the function, and thus not cause an error due to too many parameters when calling `FN()`, when `FN()` points to a specific function (`fn2(int)` in this case).

Am I doing this correctly, or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like MSVC is not using the `test_derived` partial specialization, as you can see by printing out `x2.fn_specified`.  I see MSVC 2015 has "partial support for expression SFINAE" - I wonder if that could be the issue.

Comment: @aschepler,  where did you get that quote from?

Comment: Ok, I've filed a bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3136149). If others would like to upvote it to raise its priority for it to get fixed, that'd be great.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/02/partial-support-for-expression-sfinae-in-vs-2015-update-1/ But I don't see this case in either the "supported" or "unsupported" examples.

Comment: I tried to use VC++ 2017 and at least compiler build 19.10.25019.0 was able to compile this code.  This prolly means that VC++ 2015 will not see this fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construct you are using is called Expression SFINAE. Visual Studio until 2017 doesn't declare to [support it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). Visual Studio 2015's updates enables partial support (read more about [update 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/02/partial-support-for-expression-sfinae-in-vs-2015-update-1/), [updates 1, 2 and 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/expression-sfinae-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3/)). Nevertheless to make it work in MSVC in all versions one need to create workarounds that does not involve expression e.g. inside template specialization parameter. To achieve it in your case one can use pattern matching with additional layer of indirection (e.g. std::integral_constant):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int fn1()    { return 1; }
int fn2(int) { return 2; }

template <typename FN_T, FN_T FN, typename DERIVED>
class test_base
{
    template <typename T = DERIVED, typename = std::enable_if_t<!T::fn_specified>>
    int fn()
    {
        return FN();
    }

public:
    int fn_indirect()
    {
        return static_cast<DERIVED*>(this)->fn();
    }
};

template <class FN_T>
class test_derived : public test_base<typename FN_T::value_type, FN_T::value, test_derived<FN_T>>
{
public:
    static constexpr bool fn_specified = false;
};

template <typename FN_T>
class test_derived<std::integral_constant<FN_T, &fn2>>
    : public test_base<FN_T, &fn2, test_derived<std::integral_constant<FN_T, &fn2>>>
{
    using base = test_base<FN_T, &fn2, test_derived<std::integral_constant<FN_T, &fn2>>>;
    friend base;

public:
    static constexpr bool fn_specified = true;
    int fn()
    {
        return fn2(1);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    test_derived<std::integral_constant<decltype(&fn1), &fn1>> x1;
    test_derived<std::integral_constant<decltype(&fn2), &fn2>> x2;

    std::cout << x1.fn_indirect() << " ";

    // comment next line out and it will work
    std::cout << x2.fn_indirect() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://rextester.com/NNOSIW59448)

Comment: So pattern matching worked where SFINAE failed?  Interesting.

Comment: SFINAE expression failed (`FN == &fn2` inside specialization) as MSVC doesn't hide that they don't support it.

Comment: Didn't know that they didn't hide the fact.  :) The expression didn't fail, I think it was the comparison in the template parameter list.  Don't need to use an indirection, just don't compare pointers and use pattern matching till MS C++ 2017.

Comment: @Adrian see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/06/19/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-rtm/) in particular note [1]: `We’re planning to start implementing Expression SFINAE in the compiler immediately after 2015 RTM, and we’re planning to deliver it in an Update to 2015, supported for production use.  (But not necessarily 2015 Update 1.  It might take longer.)`

Comment: @Adrian PS comparison is an expression and in context of template specialization parameter is an expression sfinae...

Comment: So, what I'm seeing is an incomplete implementation of Expression SFINAE.  Good to know.

Comment: @Adrian unfortunately I wasn't able to find official rationale behind not implementing Expression SFINAE available on Microsoft pages... It was actually kind of funny :)

Comment: Specify in the answer that VC++2015 doesn't support Expression SFINAE, how to use pattern matching in place of it and I'll mark this as answered.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to introduce a new type `FooT`.  You might as well use `std::integral_constant` as it is standard and clearer.

Comment: @Adrian personally I'm not keen of using integral_constant in such purpose as it's name makes me think it is integer value, but yes it is possible to use it in this purpose. Edited